# How to install mayavi on google Colab?

Tags: python, pip, vtk, google-colaboratory, mayavi

I tried installing [mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html#installing-with-conda-forge) on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Cfu4oC0cpFmtyBjMjp3uF3DlqKrDdMOo) using pip:

```
!pip install mayavi
```

This threw the following error:

> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mayavi ... error

The rest of the error output is available at the [Colab document](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Cfu4oC0cpFmtyBjMjp3uF3DlqKrDdMOo).

---

**Solution: Work in Progress**

Following the response from [@Bob-Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8841057/bob-smith), I found that his solution needed a slight change for installing the dependencies:

`!apt-get install vtk6`
`!apt-get install libvtk6-dev python-vtk6`

---

**Problems Faced and Workaround Found (PFWF)**

**PFWF-001** `!apt-get install python-vtk` throws the following error:

> Package 'python-vtk' has no installation candidate

I found a [command-reference](http://kazenotaiyo.blogspot.com/2010/06/installing-vtk-in-ubuntu-and-making.html) for this:

`!apt-get install libvtk5-dev python-vtk`

However, this command also did not work. The package name had changed from `libvtk5-dev` to `libvtk6-dev` and the [**python binding for VTK**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libvtk6-dev) has changed from `python-vtk` to `python-vtk6`. Clearly this kind of change will continue to happen in future and you may need to check the package name and the python binding for [VTK](https://www.vtk.org/download/) before running the following statement:

> `!apt-get install libvtk6-dev python-vtk6`

**Note:** If you are here looking to solve VTK installation problems for python and this does not solve that you may want to look here: [installing-vtk-for-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383666/installing-vtk-for-python)

---

**Installing `mayavi` still throws error:**
Although the two steps above install the dependencies, the last line: `!pip install mayavi` spits out the following **error**:

> Could not connect to any X display.

## The latest progress on Mayavi installation can be found here.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K_VIP9izNLKalD_IgBSiTowyNkU7aWcW

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I tried those commands but after a point the progress stops: ```Setting up qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-mono (16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...```

Comment: I have added a fresh copy of my latest installation effort in this [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K_VIP9izNLKalD_IgBSiTowyNkU7aWcW) document. importing **`mlab`** throws error now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to install deps. Run

```
!apt-get install vtk6
!apt-get install python-vtk
!pip install mayavi
```

If you've attempted to import `myavi` before installing the deps, you may need to restart you runtime before executing the `!pip install myavi` command using the Runtime -> Restart runtime menu.

Comment: Thank you @BobSmith. "!apt-get install python-vtk" did not execute without error. Source was not available.

Comment: `!pip install mayavi` throws error after the dependencies are installed. Details are updated in the main description.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and I was getting error like this. So I tried install vtk package with conda. You need conda to install vtk of course so:

```
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 ujson
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
import ujson
print(ujson.dumps({1:2}))
!conda --version
```

Then set up vtk package with conda as:

```
!apt-get install vtk6
!conda install -c anaconda vtk
```

I was trying to install mayavi for mne package so:

```
!conda activate mne
!conda install gxx_linux-64=7.3
!pip install https://api.github.com/repos/enthought/mayavi/zipball/226189a6ad3dc3c01d031ef21d0d0cde554ac851
```

Be careful because you need to mne package to activate so before installing mayavi (I was trying to install mne as I said before):

```
!pip install mne
```